# How to test first form control of angular form is focused on page load using jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I am using followed code to focus on first input field once the page has been loaded using context

```
this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('input')[0].focus();
```

How to test whether field has been focused by unit tests and e2e's in angular 6

```
component.modelForm = new ModelForm(null, {});
      component.form.addControl('test', new FormControl(null));
      component.form.addControl('test1', new FormControl(null));
      fixture.detectChanges();
      console.log(fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input')))
```

I am adding formcontrols in unit test as above.

And html component will be "< configure-form >< /configure-form>"

Based on input fields I will load the form using formcontrol fields

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, check if `focus` method was called or not on that particular `input` element. To achieve this you have to spy on `inputEl.focus()`

```
it('Input el should be focused', () => {
    let inputEl = comp.el.nativeElement.queryAll(By.css('input'))[0];
    spyOn(inputEl ,'focus');
    comp.ngOnInit();
    expect(inputEl.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: I am using this code to get input field but getting error as "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"

const input = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input'))[0].nativeElement

The formfields are added using @Input decorators here

Can u suggest how to get input field..

Comment: What does `fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input'))` print? Is it an empty array?

Comment: Yes fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input')) this is giving [], empty array

Comment: Can you show your html code and unit test code aswell? Please add them to your question.